# Graphics not correctly produced when saving to PDF in Version 12

Tags: graphics, bugs, pdf-format, printing

12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 6, 2019)

How do I get my graphic to look the same in PDF as it does in a Notebook?

This is what the graphic looks like in the FrontEnd:

[image]

This is how the same image appears in a PDF file:

[image]

This is the code producing the graphics.

```
    Module[{arc, \[GothicC]a, \[GothicC]b, \[GothicC]c, \
\[ScriptCapitalC]a, \[ScriptCapitalC]b, \[ScriptCapitalC]c, \[Theta]a \
= 2/3 \[Pi], \[Theta]b = 4/3 \[Pi], \[Theta]c = 0
  , \[CapitalTheta], \[CapitalDelta]\[CapitalTheta]
  , \[CapitalDelta]\[Theta]1 = \[Pi], \[CapitalDelta]\[Theta]2 = \
\[Pi]/3, \[GothicCapitalR]}
 , \[GothicC]a = {0, 0}; \[GothicC]b = {1, 
   0}; \[GothicC]c = \[GothicC]b/
   2 + {0, 1} Sqrt[3]/
    2; \[GothicCapitalR][\[Theta]_] := {Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]]};
 arc[\[GothicC]_, \[Theta]_, \[CapitalDelta]\[Theta]_] := (\[GothicC] \
+ \[GothicCapitalR][#]) & /@ 
   Range[\[Theta], \[Theta] + \[CapitalDelta]\[Theta], \
\[CapitalDelta]\[Theta]/180];
 \[CapitalDelta]\[CapitalTheta] = {0, \[Pi], 4/3 \[Pi], 5/3 \[Pi]};
 \[CapitalTheta][\[Theta]_, 
   i_] := \[Theta] + \[CapitalDelta]\[CapitalTheta][[i]];
 
 \[ScriptCapitalC]a = {arc[\[GothicC]a, \[CapitalTheta][\[Theta]a, 
     1], \[CapitalDelta]\[Theta]1], 
   arc[\[GothicC]a, \[CapitalTheta][\[Theta]a, 
     2], \[CapitalDelta]\[Theta]2], 
   arc[\[GothicC]a, \[CapitalTheta][\[Theta]a, 
     3], \[CapitalDelta]\[Theta]2], 
   arc[\[GothicC]a, \[CapitalTheta][\[Theta]a, 
     4], \[CapitalDelta]\[Theta]2]};
 \[ScriptCapitalC]b = {arc[\[GothicC]b, \[CapitalTheta][\[Theta]b, 
     1], \[CapitalDelta]\[Theta]1], 
   arc[\[GothicC]b, \[CapitalTheta][\[Theta]b, 
     2], \[CapitalDelta]\[Theta]2], 
   arc[\[GothicC]b, \[CapitalTheta][\[Theta]b, 
     3], \[CapitalDelta]\[Theta]2], 
   arc[\[GothicC]b, \[CapitalTheta][\[Theta]b, 
     4], \[CapitalDelta]\[Theta]2]};
 \[ScriptCapitalC]c = {arc[\[GothicC]c, \[CapitalTheta][\[Theta]c, 
     1], \[CapitalDelta]\[Theta]1], 
   arc[\[GothicC]c, \[CapitalTheta][\[Theta]c, 
     2], \[CapitalDelta]\[Theta]2], 
   arc[\[GothicC]c, \[CapitalTheta][\[Theta]c, 
     3], \[CapitalDelta]\[Theta]2], 
   arc[\[GothicC]c, \[CapitalTheta][\[Theta]c, 
     4], \[CapitalDelta]\[Theta]2]};
 
 Graphics[{Thickness[0.02], 
   Point[{\[GothicC]a, \[GothicC]b, \[GothicC]c}]
   , {Red, Line[\[ScriptCapitalC]a[[1]]], 
    Point[\[GothicC]a + \[GothicCapitalR][\[CapitalTheta][\[Theta]a, 
        1]]]}
   , {Blue, Line[\[ScriptCapitalC]a[[2]]]}
   , {Green, Line[\[ScriptCapitalC]a[[3]]]}
   , {Magenta, Line[\[ScriptCapitalC]a[[4]]]}
   , {Red, Line[\[ScriptCapitalC]b[[1]]]}
   , {Blue, Line[\[ScriptCapitalC]b[[2]]]}
   , {Green, Line[\[ScriptCapitalC]b[[3]]]}
   , {Magenta, Line[\[ScriptCapitalC]b[[4]]]}
   , {Red, Line[\[ScriptCapitalC]c[[1]]]}
   , {Blue, Line[\[ScriptCapitalC]c[[2]]]}
   , {Green, Line[\[ScriptCapitalC]c[[3]]]}
   , {Magenta, Line[\[ScriptCapitalC]c[[4]]]}
   , {Blue
    , Polygon[
     Join[\[ScriptCapitalC]a[[1]], \[ScriptCapitalC]b[[
       4]], \[ScriptCapitalC]c[[2]]]]
    , Polygon[
     Join[\[ScriptCapitalC]b[[1]], \[ScriptCapitalC]c[[
       4]], \[ScriptCapitalC]a[[2]]]]
    , Polygon[
     Join[\[ScriptCapitalC]c[[1]], \[ScriptCapitalC]a[[
       4]], \[ScriptCapitalC]b[[2]]]]
    , Polygon[
     Join[\[ScriptCapitalC]c[[3]], \[ScriptCapitalC]a[[
       3]], \[ScriptCapitalC]b[[3]]]]
    }
   }]
 ]
```

Comment: I reproduce your problem in v12, and it's even worse in v12.1: https://imgur.com/a/WpLnqWS

Comment: That's what I'm good at.  Breaking stuff.

Comment: Seems to me like MMA's PDF writer is pretty good at breaking stuff...

Comment: Please report this to Support.

Comment: No problem with this graphics in the PDF produced by Mathematica 8.0.4, the PDF looks identically to the FrontEnd. It would be nice to check it using versions 9, 10 and 11, if someone has access.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems like there are two main problems.

**One is the shape of the polygons**

```
test = Graphics@Polygon[Join[\[ScriptCapitalC]a[[1]], \[ScriptCapitalC]b[[4]], \
\[ScriptCapitalC]c[[2]]]]
```

[image]

Gives this in the PDF:

[image]

Plotting the points gives a clue to why:

```
ListPlot[Join[\[ScriptCapitalC]a[[1]], \[ScriptCapitalC]b[[4]], \
\[ScriptCapitalC]c[[2]]], Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Changing the order of some points helps:

```
ListPlot[Join[\[ScriptCapitalC]a[[1]], 
  Reverse@\[ScriptCapitalC]b[[4]], Reverse@\[ScriptCapitalC]c[[2]]], 
 Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

And

```
test2 = Graphics@Polygon[Join[\[ScriptCapitalC]a[[1]], 
    Reverse@\[ScriptCapitalC]b[[4]], Reverse@\[ScriptCapitalC]c[[2]]]]
```

Gives the expected PDF:

[image]

**The other main problem is that the lines are hidden.**
This can be fixed by drawing the lines after the polygons.

Using both of these workarounds:

```
Graphics[{
  {Blue, Polygon[
    Join[\[ScriptCapitalC]a[[1]], Reverse@\[ScriptCapitalC]b[[4]], Reverse@\[ScriptCapitalC]c[[2]]]], Polygon[Join[\[ScriptCapitalC]b[[1]], Reverse@\[ScriptCapitalC]c[[4]], Reverse@\[ScriptCapitalC]a[[2]]]], 
   Polygon[Join[\[ScriptCapitalC]c[[1]], Reverse@\[ScriptCapitalC]a[[4]], Reverse@\[ScriptCapitalC]b[[2]]]], Polygon[Join[\[ScriptCapitalC]c[[3]], \[ScriptCapitalC]a[[3]], \
\[ScriptCapitalC]b[[3]]]]},
  Thickness[0.01], Point[{\[GothicC]a, \[GothicC]b, \[GothicC]c}], {Red, Line[\[ScriptCapitalC]a[[1]]], Point[\[GothicC]a + \[GothicCapitalR][\[CapitalTheta][\[Theta]a, 
       1]]]}, {Blue, Line[\[ScriptCapitalC]a[[2]]]}, {Green, Line[\[ScriptCapitalC]a[[3]]]}, {Magenta, Line[\[ScriptCapitalC]a[[4]]]}, {Red, Line[\[ScriptCapitalC]b[[1]]]}, {Blue, Line[\[ScriptCapitalC]b[[2]]]}, {Green, Line[\[ScriptCapitalC]b[[3]]]}, {Magenta, Line[\[ScriptCapitalC]b[[4]]]}, {Red, Line[\[ScriptCapitalC]c[[1]]]}, {Blue, Line[\[ScriptCapitalC]c[[2]]]}, {Green, Line[\[ScriptCapitalC]c[[3]]]}, {Magenta, Line[\[ScriptCapitalC]c[[4]]]}
  }]
```

[image]

Gives PDF:

[image]